# jQuery changing the name of a field

Tags: jquery

im trying to change the name of a field on the change state of a select list.

I have the following code

```
<script>
$('#selectintrole').change(function(){
    $('#proven_keyname').val($(this).val());
};
</script>

<select name="item_options" id="selectintrole">
<option value="20030">Universal (20030)</option>
<option value="4545456">Medium (4545456)</option>
<option value="15447">Large (15447)</option>
</select>

<input name="proven" value="1" type="checkbox" id="proven_keyname" />
```

It doesnt seem to be doing anything though ... when i check the generated source, nothing has changed .... am i missing something?

Comment: Because it needs to be ticked

Comment: What do you want to happen to the value?

Comment: Not to the value .... i want the name of the checkbox to change to the value of the chosen select option

Comment: Then you should call `.attr('name', ...)`.

Comment: Is there any chance you could write the whole function ... ive added what you recommened and its still not working.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/9PpUz/

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to bind your change event after the document is ready like so

```
     $(function () {

        $('#selectintrole').change(function () {

            $('#proven_keyname').val($(this).val());
        });

    });
```

If you want to change the name attribute then replace with this

```
$('#proven_keyname').attr('name', $(this).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running before the elements exist.

Move the script below the HTML, or wrap it in `$(function() { ... })`, which will run it when the page loads.

**EDIT**: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/9PpUz/)

Comment: @Cecil: You're also missing a `)` after the handler.

Comment: Does .val($(this).val()); just change the 'value' or will it change the 'name' of the checkbox?

Comment: @Cecil: For checkboxes, it will check the matched checkboxes with those names.  You may want to call `.attr('value', string)`.